# Use of semaphores for matrix multiplication

Tags: shared-memory, semaphore, matrix-multiplication

Would I need semaphores to synchronize processes in matrix multiplication using multiple processes when processes are dealing with different rows . Would it still create race codition?

Answer (score 0):

If different threads are dealing with different rows, then there shouldn't be any danger of two threads accessing the same memory location, so there shouldn't be a reason to worry about race conditions.